# Вопрос про слово "впрочем"

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

> Я думал, что Костя Зиберов говорил о своем приезде в Петербург просто так, чтобы сказать мне что-нибудь приятное и удовлетворить палящую, ненасытную жажду общительности и дружелюбия. Так, один господин из Кишинева, встретив меня случайно в Петербурге и познакомившись, пригласил к себе в Кишинев «денька на два». И он знал прекрасно, что никогда я к нему не приеду, и все-таки приглашал, а я был твердо уверен, что нет такой силы, которая повлекла бы меня за тысячи верст к еле знакомому человеку «денька на два», — и все-таки я обещал. Впрочем, сейчас же мы оба и забыли об этом.

Можно ли изъять из последнего предложения слово "впрочем"? Почему-то оно создаёт у меня маленький диссонанс.

Comment: Точку ставят после кавычек всегда.

Answer (score 2):

Можно, но не нужно. Можно заменить на *"однако",* а лучше не трогать. Почему? Потому что нарушается *связность повествования.* Оно обеспечивает переход от одной мысли к другой. Если вы к нему попросту не привыкли, ничего — привыкайте. Оно не пустое.